# Javascript let user choose element

Tags: javascript, html

https://gyazo.com/aa49eb6d6849b3adabb8924aa9e40594

I have the elements in the diagram and I want to let the user choose in which element they are going to add the semi column to add text, but I dont know how to let them select a element and then add according to that selection.

```
var addDetail = document.getElementById('addDetail');
var clauseInput = document.getElementsByClassName('clause');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if(target == clauseInput[0] || target == clauseInput[1] ||
           target == clauseInput[2] || target == clauseInput[3] ||  
           target == clauseInput[4] || target == addDetail) {
            document.getElementById('addDetail').style.display='inline-block';
            // createDetail();
            console.log(target);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('addDetail').style.display='none';
        }
}, false);
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or similar to illustrate your problem, please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybocn6k9/

Comment: When a click on the blue input I want to let it show a button and click on that button to create a column inside that element.

Comment: Not clear what issue is after user selects input. Need to be a lot more specific

Comment: the problem is when I try to create the column it "forgets" the element previous selected because it clicks on the "add Detail" and thats becames the new selected input.

Comment: I want to be able to choose in which column I want to add a sub-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Instead of searching through all clause elements every time when addDetail been clicked, there is **e.relatedTarget** that really suitable to your problem, [detailed documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget), and the update snippet :

```js
/*CREATE TOP AND BOTTOM CLAUSES*/
/*Top Clauses*/
const addClauseTop = document.querySelector('#addClauseTop');
var targetClauseElement;
var addDetail = document.getElementById('addDetail');
addDetail.addEventListener('focusin', function(e) {
  createDetail(e.relatedTarget);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e) {
 if ( e.currentTarget != addDetail ) {
   addDetail.style.display='none';
 }
});


var firstTopClause = document.getElementsByClassName('clause')[0];
firstTopClause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  addDetail.style.display='inline-block';
}); 

var firstBottomClause = document.getElementsByClassName('clauseDivReverse')[0];
firstBottomClause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  addDetail.style.display='inline-block';
}); 



addClauseTop.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 //Get Divs-Overlay
 const topDivs = document.querySelector('#topClauses');
 const bottomDivs = document.querySelector('#bottomClauses');

 // Create Elements
 const clauseDiv = document.createElement('div');
 const clauseText = document.createElement('input');
 const clauseStroke = document.createElement('div');
  
 // // //Give Style
 clauseDiv.classList.add('clauseDiv');
  clauseDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    addDetail.style.display='inline-block';
  }); 
 clauseText.classList.add('clause');
 clauseText.setAttribute("id", "clause");
 clauseStroke.classList.add('strokeClause');
  //
 // // Append to document
 clauseDiv.appendChild(clauseText);
 clauseDiv.appendChild(clauseStroke);
 topDivs.appendChild(clauseDiv);
 document.body.appendChild(topDivs);
 document.body.appendChild(bottomDivs);
  
})
/*BOTTOM Clauses*/
const addClauseBottom = document.querySelector('#addClauseBottom');
addClauseBottom.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 //Get Divs-Overlay
 const topDivs = document.querySelector('#topClauses');
 const bottomDivs = document.querySelector('#bottomClauses');

 // Create Elements
 const clauseDiv = document.createElement('div');
  clauseDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    targetClauseElement = e.currentTarget; 
    addDetail.style.display='inline-block';
  }); 
 const clauseText = document.createElement('input');
 const clauseStroke = document.createElement('div');

 // // //Give Style
 clauseDiv.classList.add('clauseDivReverse');
 clauseText.classList.add('clauseReverse');
  clauseText.setAttribute("id", "clauseReverse");
 clauseStroke.classList.add('strokeClauseReverse');
  //
 // // Append to document
 clauseDiv.appendChild(clauseText);
 clauseDiv.appendChild(clauseStroke);
 bottomDivs.appendChild(clauseDiv);
 document.body.appendChild(bottomDivs);
})
/***********/



//Create a addDetail
function createDetail(target){

      var mainColumn = target.parentElement;
      var strokeColumn = mainColumn.children[1];
      // Create Elements
      var levelOneDiv = document.createElement('div');
      var levelOneText = document.createElement('input');

      if ( mainColumn.classList.contains('clauseDiv') ) {
        levelOneDiv.classList.add('levelOneClauseReverse');
         levelOneText.classList.add('levelOneTextReverse');
         //I thought you have not completed your style yet, like something levelOneClause class
      } else {
         levelOneDiv.classList.add('levelOneClauseReverse');
         levelOneText.classList.add('levelOneTextReverse');          
      }

      levelOneDiv.appendChild(levelOneText);
      strokeColumn.appendChild(levelOneDiv);

  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn+SC');

body{
 margin: 10%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
h1{
 color: #3B3C3D;
 font-family: 'Vollkorn SC', serif;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align:center;
}
h2{
 color: #3B3C3D;
 font-family: 'Vollkorn SC', serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align:center;
}
#bottomClauses{
 clear: both;
 float: right;
}
/*CONTROL-PANEL*/
#controlPanel{
 float: inline-block;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: 20%;
 margin-bottom: 15%;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 border-radius: 10%;
 border-bottom: 0.1vw solid #3B3C3D;
}
.addClause{
 background-color: #2c3e50;
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 padding: 0.5em;
 border: 0;
 color: #FFF;
}
.addClause:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000;
}
.addDetail{
 display: none;
 background-color: #2c3e50;
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 padding: 0.5em;
 border: 0;
 color: #FFF;
}
.addDetail:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000;
}
/*FISHBONE*/
#fishBone{
 position: relative;
 float:right;
 top: 19.75vw;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0.2vw;
 background-color: #34495e;
}
#finalResult{
 position: absolute;
 /*float:right;*/
 left: 83.5vw;
 top: 44.25vw;
 width: 7.5vw;
 height: 7.5vw;
 padding: 1vw;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #7f8c8d;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 0.15vw solid #34495e;
}
/*NEW CLAUSE*/
.clauseDiv{
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
 width: 5vw;
 margin-right: 12.5vw;
}
.clause{
 float: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -3.5vw;
 right: 2vw;
 text-align: center;
 width: 5.8vw;
 height: 1.5vw;
 padding: 0.2vw;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #3498db;
 border-radius: 0.15vw;
 border: 0;
}
.strokeClause{
 position: relative;
 top: -5.75vw;
 transform: rotate(-25deg);
 background-color: #34495e;
 width: 0.1vw;
 height: 25vw;
 margin-left: 7.5vw;
 border: 0.05vw solid #34495e;
 border-radius: 0.1vw;
 float: inline-block;
 z-index: -1;
}
/*NEW CLAUSE REVERSE*/
.clauseDivReverse{
 float: inline-block;
 float:right;
 width: 5vw;
 margin-right: 12.5vw;
}
.clauseReverse{
 position: relative;
 top: 15.5vw;
 right: 2.5vw;
 float: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 5.8vw;
 height: 1.5vw;
 padding: 0.2vw;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #3498db;
 border-radius: 0.15vw;
 border: 0;
}
.strokeClauseReverse{
 position: relative;
 top: -9.75vw;
 transform: rotate(25deg);
 background-color: #34495e;
 width: 0.1vw;
 height: 25vw;
 margin-left: 7.5vw;
 border: 0.05vw solid #34495e;
 border-radius: 0.1vw;
 float: inline-block;
 z-index: -1;
}
/*NEW LEVEL ONE*/
.levelOneClauseReverse{
 margin-bottom: 5vw;
}
.levelOneTextReverse{
 border: 0;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 0.75vw;
 width: 13vw;
 top: 4.5vw;
 right: 12.75vw;
 border-bottom: 0.1vw solid #34495e;
 transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Diagram Editor</h1>
  <div id='controlPanel'>
   <h2>Control Panel</h2>
   <input type='submit' name='addClause' value='Clause on TOP' class='addClause' id='addClauseTop'>
   <input type='submit' name='addClause' value='Clause on BOTTOM' class='addClause' id='addClauseBottom'>
   <input type='submit' name='addClause' value='Add Detail' class='addDetail' id='addDetail'>
  </div>
  <div id='fishBone'></div>
   <input type='text' name='clause' id='finalResult'>
  <div  id='topClauses'>
   <div class='clauseDiv'>
    <input class='clause' id='clause'>
    <div class='strokeClause'>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottomClauses'>
   <div class='clauseDivReverse' >
    <input class='clauseReverse clause'>
    <div class='strokeClauseReverse'>
     <div class='levelOneClauseReverse'>
       <input class='levelOneTextReverse'>
     </div>
     <div class='levelOneClauseReverse'>
       <input class='levelOneTextReverse'>
     </div>
     <div class='levelOneClauseReverse'>
       <input class='levelOneTextReverse'>
     </div>
     <div class='levelOneClauseReverse'>
       <input class='levelOneTextReverse'>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: What I'm talking about adding a sub column is what I did in the next code.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybocn6k9/4/

The problem is I can't choose on which main column I'll create a sub-column because the program chooses the last one created automatically.